# Retrieve Texts from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I would like to know the answers of the following queries,

1. What is the maximum size of data a TEXT data type can have in mysql table?
2. If I would like to store 6000 to 7000 lines of texts (say, LARGE Text) in a particular field what should be the datatype of that field?
3. What is the process to retrieve the LARGE TEXT data from mysql table in the following two cases using PHP,

Case-1 : Retrieve data from a particular field "Messages"

```
---------------------------
id   |   Messages
---------------------------
1    |  "here LARGE Text...
```

Case-2 : Retrieve all "Messages" data  from a the table.

```
---------------------------
id   |   Messages
---------------------------
1    |  "here LARGE Text... 
---------------------------
2    | "here another LARGE Text...
```

Comment: You can google all 3 of those questions...

Comment: @Epodax Google is too complex

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html

Comment: Case 1: `SELECT Messages FROM tableName WHERE id=1`; Case 2: `SELECT Messages FROM tableName` ; **You have to replace** `tableName` with your own table name

Comment: @Nordenheim Properly, I mean, I wish google would make it more simple to use their service.

Comment: Okey, 1 and 2 can be answered from the "TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, and LONGTEXT maximum storage sizes".

Comment: @fusion3k , that's the column of the fild will displayed, but how to get the data in .txt or .doc format?

Answer (score 0):

1. Maximum size of `TEXT` data type is **65,535 bytes** - *[reference](http://boolean.co.nz/blog/max-length-for-mysql-text-field-types/135/)*
2. 6000-7000 lines of texts can be in **`TEXT`** or, if too long, **`MEDIUMTEXT`** (16,777,215 bytes ~16MB) - *[reference](http://boolean.co.nz/blog/max-length-for-mysql-text-field-types/135/)*
3. **Same as any other MySQL retrieval format**. For example, using PDO:

---

```
// Create connection
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');

//Create and execute query
$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT `messages` FROM `table`");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo $row["messages"];
}
```

Comment: I mean to say , is it possible to get the LARGE texts in .txt of .doc file from the database?

Comment: MEDIUMTEXT could be appropriate for me

Comment: @user1328007 That question doesn't make sense... If it's in your database, it's not in a `txt` or `.doc` file, it's in the database!

Comment: yes, but is it possible to retrieve the data in those form

Comment: So the above query can fetch all the messages (of different rows) of case 2?